# Jtable list-action url with query string parameter always sending old parameter value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable

I have a jtable showing data in my MVC c# web application, 
I have a 2 dropdowns (cascade) and jtable in my view and jquery script.

On selection of 2nd dropdown I am setting a url,
listaction url is initialized as below.

```
var url = 'getdata/repointinglist?IDs=' +id + '&id2='+idd;
```

I am initializing "idd" and "id" variables on every time dropdownlist selection is changed and this will call method

```
[httppost]
[Nocache]
    public JsonResult repointinglist(int IDs,int id2)  .
    {


    }
```

using below code

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

for first time
On the event of change of 2nd dropdown jtabel loaded correctly .

I have added below to no cache too.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

For second or further calls
on dropdown list selection changed I am getting function call but the parameters value I am getting is not getting refreshed for call only!!!.

the value which get set on first call remain there !!.

Although in alertbox the value of url just before the call made is shown correct but don't know why controller not getting the updated variables value!!

Is there any way other I can set or access the dropdown's id inside the JsonResult action ? all i need to know what ID is selected by user any how in code .

Comment: Show your jquery-jtable code. From where `id` and `idd` values are coming?

Comment: I have dropdown's  selected_ddl_src1 and selected_ddl_src2 on there change i am initializing these 2 ids......$("selected_ddl_src2").chanage(fucntion(){var id = $("selected_ddl_src2").val(); var idd = $("selected_ddl_src1").val();} @abpatil

Comment: As I already said Show your jquery-jtable code. Without taking look at it we cant help you.

Comment: Also there is a method [data.clearCache()](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/FieldOptions), have you tried this?

Comment: "Jtable “listaction” url always calling action controller with old parameters value MVC4 Jquery " i have posted new question with my code please check  ...I did not use data.clearCache() were to use it . @abpatil